nginx wont show site.com/statz - why?
I've configured nginx to host a website at website.com, blog.website.com, but now when I make a new config in /etc/nginx/sites-available - it wont allow me to access content in the path: website.com/statz .
It HTTP 404's, and the error/access log I have defined dont have anything in them.
What may be going wrong?
For brevity I am showing all (3) configs for website.com, blog.website.com, and website.com/statz.
website.com
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    root /home/path/to/website;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

blog.website.com
server {
    listen 80;
    root /home/usr/website/blog;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  blog.website.com;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }
    location = /favicon.ico {
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
        expires max;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    location = /robots.txt {
        allow all;
        log_not_found off;
        access_log off;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
         include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
         include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

not working website.com/statz
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com;
}
server {
    server_name website.com; 
    access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;

    root /home/usr/statz/; 

    index index.php;

    location /statz/ {
    alias /home/usr/statz;
    }

    ## only allow accessing the following php files
    location ~ ^statz/(index|matomo|piwik|js/index|plugins/HeatmapSessionRecording/configs)\.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; # if your Nginx setup doesn't come with a default fastcgi-php config, you can fetch it from https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/fastcgi.conf
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404; # protects against CVE-2019-11043. If this line is already included in your snippets/fastcgi-php.conf you can comment it here.
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; # prohibit httpoxy: https://httpoxy.org/
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock; #replace with the path to your PHP socket file
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # uncomment if you are using PHP via TCP sockets (e.g. Docker container)
    }

    ## deny access to all other .php files
    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    ## serve all other files normally
    location /statz {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    ## disable all access to the following directories
    location ~ ^statz/(config|tmp|core|lang) {
        deny all;
        return 403; # replace with 404 to not show these directories exist
    }

    location ~ /statz\.ht {
        deny  all;
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ statz/js/container_.*_preview\.js$ {
        expires off;
        add_header Cache-Control 'private, no-cache, no-store';
    }

    location ~ statz\.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
        allow all;
        ## Cache images,CSS,JS and webfonts for an hour
        ## Increasing the duration may improve the load-time, but may cause old files to show after an Matomo upgrade
        expires 1h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ ^statz/(libs|vendor|plugins|misc|node_modules) {
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    ## properly display textfiles in root directory
    location ~statz/(.*\.md|LEGALNOTICE|LICENSE) {
        default_type text/plain;
    }
}

The logs are empty, and when I visit website.com/statz - it http404s. I am trying to setup matomo but the config provided is not working in my case (https://github.com/matomo-org/matomo-nginx/blob/master/sites-available/matomo.conf)
What am I doing wrong? Thank you so much

Can you clarify if the website file path is this:
root /home/usr/statz/;

or this one:
root /home/usr/website/statz/;

Also, did you add the right permissions to this website directory path /home/usr/statz. You can try copying and pasting these two command lines on your server terminal:
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /home/usr/statz
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/usr/statz

How to Configure Nginx to host multiple websites

Thanks for the answer. /home/usr/statz is the path.
The permissions are set.

if you can please assist. Thank you.

Did you create each configuration file independently?

Yes i did, All separate

thoughts on this?

are you there to help?

Hi and welcome! Please avoid putting questions or comments in the answer section unless you have a verified answer to the original question. Thanks.

When you're not getting even the errors logged - verify that your requests are reaching the right server.
Get the IP address your requests get sent to: use nslookup website.com (available on Windows too), or even just ping. It's important that you run this on the same computer where you see 404 errors.
Once you have the IP address, compare it with the address of your server. If they don't match - you need to update DNS records for your website.

You have two server blocks for website.com virtual host. If you really want to have /home/usr/statz visible under website.com, make your first website.com look like following:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name website.com www.website.com;
    root /home/path/to/website;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    index index.php;

    location /statz/ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        alias /home/usr/statz;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    ## only allow accessing the following php files
    location ~ ^statz/(index|matomo|piwik|js/index|plugins/HeatmapSessionRecording/configs)\.php$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf; # if your Nginx setup doesn't come with a default fastcgi-php config, you can fetch it from https://github.com/nginx/nginx/blob/master/conf/fastcgi.conf
        try_files $fastcgi_script_name =404; # protects against CVE-2019-11043. If this line is already included in your snippets/fastcgi-php.conf you can comment it here.
        fastcgi_param HTTP_PROXY ""; # prohibit httpoxy: https://httpoxy.org/
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock; #replace with the path to your PHP socket file
        #fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000; # uncomment if you are using PHP via TCP sockets (e.g. Docker container)
    }

    ## deny access to all other .php files
    location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    ## disable all access to the following directories
    location ~ ^statz/(config|tmp|core|lang) {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        deny all;
        return 403; # replace with 404 to not show these directories exist
    }

    location ~ /statz\.ht {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        deny  all;
        return 403;
    }

    location ~ statz/js/container_.*_preview\.js$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        expires off;
        add_header Cache-Control 'private, no-cache, no-store';
    }

    location ~ statz\.(gif|ico|jpg|png|svg|js|css|htm|html|mp3|mp4|wav|ogg|avi|ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$ {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        allow all;
        ## Cache images,CSS,JS and webfonts for an hour
        ## Increasing the duration may improve the load-time, but may cause old files to show after an Matomo upgrade
        expires 1h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public";
    }

    location ~ ^statz/(libs|vendor|plugins|misc|node_modules) {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        deny all;
        return 403;
    }

    ## properly display textfiles in root directory
    location ~statz/(.*\.md|LEGALNOTICE|LICENSE) {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/statz-access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/statzerror.log;
        default_type text/plain;
    }
}

You can disable logging by using access_log off; for those locations where logging is irrelevant.

It's likely the second block would have been intended for service with TLS/SSL. Is the OP behind a terminating proxy or not?

By default config files from /etc/nginx/sites-available are not included in main config.
You need to create a symlink in the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled directory that will point to the configuration file in /etc/nginx/sites-available.
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/your_config_file.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/

